# Building structs dynamically with lifetime parameters

Tags: rust, tree, lifetime

Trying to build a tree structure from another tree structure in Rust - where the the built tree structure are dependent on lifetimes parameters.

The traits below represents a simplified version of my search tree structure (the one I wish for to be build dynamically):

```rust
trait SPart {
  fn search<'b>(&'b self, queue: &mut Vec<Box<dyn SPart + 'b>>);
}
trait SubSPart<PP: SPart> {
  fn promote_search<'b>(&'b self, parent: &'b PP, queue: &mut Vec<Box<dyn SPart + 'b>>);
}

struct SP<'a>(pub Vec<Box<dyn SubSPart<Self> + 'a>>);
struct SSP(pub i32);

impl<'a> SPart for SP<'a> {
  fn search<'b>(&'b self, queue: &mut Vec<Box<dyn SPart + 'b>>) {
    for c in &self.0 {
      c.promote_search(self, queue);
    }
  }
}
impl<'a> SubSPart<SP<'a>> for SSP {
  fn promote_search<'b>(&'b self, parent: &'b SP, queue: &mut Vec<Box<dyn SPart + 'b>>) {
    queue.push(Box::new(SP(vec![])));
  }
}
```

The parts and subparts can contain references to data, hence I think the lifetime-parameter is necessary.
These parts are usually also short-lived in a recursive function, and can be created dynamically referring back to data from earlier frames in the recursive call.

This all works with flying colors, so now I'm interested in building this initial tree structure dynamically from a separate tree structure:

```rust
trait BPart {
  fn build<'b>(&'b self, v: &mut Vec<Box<dyn SPart + 'b>>);
}
trait SubBPart<P, PP: SPart> {
  fn build<'b>(&'b self, parent: &'b P, v: &mut Vec<Box<dyn SubSPart<PP> + 'b>>);
}

struct BP<'a>(pub Vec<Box<dyn SubBPart<Self, SP<'a>>>>, pub i32);
struct SBP(pub i32);

impl<'a> BPart for BP<'a> {
  fn build<'b>(&'b self, v: &mut Vec<Box<dyn SPart + 'b>>) {
    let mut sv = vec![];
    for sp in &self.0 {
      sp.build(self, &mut sv);
    }
    let sp = SP(sv);
    v.push(Box::new(sp));
  }
}

impl<'a> SubBPart<BP<'a>, SP<'a>> for SBP {
  fn build<'b>(&'b self, parent: &'b BP<'a>, v: &mut Vec<Box<dyn SubSPart<SP> + 'b>>) {
    v.push(Box::new(SSP(self.0 + parent.1)));
  }
}

fn main() {
  let bp = BP(vec![Box::new(SBP(42))], 21);
  let mut v = vec![];
  bp.build(&mut v);
}
```

However, this fails with:

```rust
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
```

It seems like the lifetime is tied to the `BPart ('a)` where I wish for the lifetime to be valid for any lifetime `('b)` at the time of creation of the `SPart` and `SubSPart`, but I'm unaware of how to express this in Rust.

[Link to rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f9aa0eb000957b2c3fe43fe9a2bb06c2)

**Edit**:
Added trait methods and examples, and main method.

Comment: A `main()` function would help understand what this is meant to do. There is a lot of indirection and it's hard to see why some things exist. e.g why are there `traits` instead of direct `impl`? How generic is this really meant to be?

For implementing a tree, [serde_json](https://github.com/serde-rs/json/blob/master/src/value/mod.rs) might be a useful example. It uses an Enum instead of traits which works quite well.

Comment: `main()` method added. The structure is part of a lib which is to be used elsewhere, as such its very generic.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite the spaghetti of lifetime constraints so I'll try to break down the limitations:

1. The lifetime `'b` is invariant due to its use in `&mut Vec<Box<dyn SPart + 'b>>`. Most lifetime annotations are covariant, meaning it can be shortened as necessary to align with other constraints. But the compiler cannot do so here because, if shortened, the value could be mutated or assigned to a value that lives shorter than it needs to.
2. The lifetime `'a` is invariant due to its use in `Vec<Box<dyn SubBPart<Self, SP<'a>>>>`. An implementor of `Trait<'a>` can use inner mutability and thus, for the same reasons above, cannot be covariant.
3. `'a: 'b` - The use of `&'b self` implies `BP<'a>: 'b` and thus implies `'a: 'b` meaning that the lifetime of `'b` cannot outlive the life of `'a`.
4. `'b: 'a` - The use of `dyn SubSPart<PP> + 'b` normally means that the trait object is allowed to borrow from `'b` but because `PP` is `SP<'a>` it is also allowed to borrow from `'a`. This means that in order for `'b` from `SubBPart::build` to line up with `BPart::build`, then `'a` cannot outlive `'b`.
5. To satisfy the above constraints, it must be that `'a == 'b`. But `'b` is part of a trait's function signature as a generic parameter, so it must be allowed to be anything.

I don't have a good recommendation for you for how to fix it since your code is very obfuscated as to what these lifetimes and trait abstractions are for.

Comment: I think you have reached the same conclusion as I, but I wonder if my example actually can be boiled down to a factory pattern, hence this might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388721/specifying-lifetimes-when-using-the-factory-pattern-in-rust ?

Comment: @timkaas Possibly, part of the solution there was to introduce a higher-kinded lifetime, `for<'a>`, to be more flexible but I'm not sure if or where that'd be useful. I also bet the constraint #4 was probably not intended but I don't know how to express what I think you want, or how to build around it.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a case where a higher kinded lifetime is needed. Instead of locking in on a specific lifetime, giving `'a` as a generic parameter in the struct `BP`, the use of a higher kinded lifetime can be specified as follows:

```rust
struct BP(pub Vec<Box<dyn for<'a> SubBPart<Self, SP<'a>>>>, pub i32);
```

To complete the answer: In my case, a `SPart` or `SubSPart` can contain references to data from its builder `BPart` or `SubBPart`. This required changes to the traits:

```rust
trait BPart<'a> {
  fn build(&'a self, v: &mut Vec<Box<dyn SPart + 'a>>);
}
trait SubBPart<'a, P, PP: SPart> {
  fn build(&'a self, parent: &'a P, v: &mut Vec<Box<dyn SubSPart<PP> + 'a>>);
}
```

and then adjusting the impls accordingly.